# Why are VST instrument not recording in cubase?

Tags: cubase

When I do a recording in cubase of the entire song onto one track, all the tracks except the VST instrument are recorded. Why are not the VST instruments recorded?

[image]

Comment: Did you have a midi input assigned? were they "red/selected to record"?

Comment: What does that mean? If I record enable tracks, the audio mixdown becomes completely silent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use file/export/audio_mixdown for recording **all** tracks that are either

1. Audio (guitar mic etc.) or
2. VST instruments.

If I have my Yamaha keyboard on a midi track it won't record this with this method - I have to set my sound card up to be "record what you hear" and record the audio from the Yamaha (driven  by the midi track) onto an audio track.

Then I do an export and it works fine.

I use C4 but for as long as I can remember this is the way to do it.

Maybe you've got a different problem or you are trying to record using a different method?

Comment: it used to work and this is now a problem just for certain projects. I suspect some hidden setting cubase since there is on/off for everything. But what is happening is that my MIDI instrument (the hardware instruments) record to the audio mixdown but not the software synths. So I checked thru all the settings and there were nothing that I could see controlled the VST (software) synths. Since the hardware synths record well and the procedure is working for other songs I suspect this is some cubase setting for this project that can't be found.

Comment: @909Niklas this sounds very strange. Good luck with it dude and certainly please let me know what you find. I shall think about this tomorrow in case the beer is stopping me tonight!!